# Dynamic reconfigure of costmaps

Tags: gazebo, navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I have a mobile robot in Gazebo with defined dimensions, whose task is to pick-up tables and to transport them to other locations. I am using move_base for path planning and navigation. The robot is navigating properly when there is no load on him, but fails to avoid obstacles when there is a table on it. Obviously, it is because dimensions of tables are not taken into account of costmaps during navigation. The question is following: is there any possibility to dynamically reconfigure or recompute my costmaps during robot motion on move_base?

My first thought was to two parallel running move_base nodes each taking control after some command, but I am not sure if this is even possible, going to try it soon, but any other/better solutions are very appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327138/dynamic-reconfigure-of-costmaps/) by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2019-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can always increase the inflation layer in you costmap params config files. You can also use dynamic reconfigure to change the inflation value on the run.

[image: image description]

Also you can change the value in your code and update the inflation parameter. This [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/12276/is-there-a-c-api-for-a-dynamic-reconfigure-client/) tackles that problem.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2019-06-28**:
in addition to changing the inflation radius, you will likely want to change the robot radius / footprint in the general costmap namespace. https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/costmap_2d/cfg/Costmap2D.cfg#L20